# Can Dynamic number of formset be used in a single view and passed o a single Template

Tags: python, django, view, formset

I have the following view,template and form through which i am implementing the formset. I intend to implement multiple formsets in a single view/template but my number of formsets is dynamic based on user input. How can i have multiple dynamic number of formsets in this code? 
Can i do this with dictionary element i.e by creating a dictionary of formsets??

My view is as follows:

```
def show (request):

 b = request.session["s1"] # count of no of period ids
 c = request.session["s2"] # account number inserted by user
 d = request.session["s3"] # year inserted by customer
 a = account_period.objects.filter(year=d).values('id')
 e = account_period.objects.filter(year=d).values('month')
 f = account_period.objects.filter(id = a).values('year') 
 butt = formset_factory(bu, extra=b)
 if request.method == 'POST'
  formset = butt(request.POST)
  if formset.is_valid():

    z = account_tab.objects.get(account_number=c)
    pr = date.today()
    i=0
    for form in formset.forms:
      x = form.cleaned_data['value']
      y = account_period.objects.get(id=a[i:(i+1)])
      try:
             uip = budget.objects.get(account_no = c,account_period = a[i:(i+1)])
             if uip.budget_amount != x
               uip.budget_amount = x
               uip.save()

      except budget.DoesNotExist:
             w = budget(account_no = z, account_period = y, budget_amount = x, created_by_login = 'me')
             w.save()
      i=i+1
    pass
    return HttpResponse('thanks')
```

form is

```
class bu(forms.Form):
   value = forms.CharField()
```

template is

```
<html>
<head>
<title>BUDGET</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>BUDGET MANAGEMENTS</p>
<p>Your Account Number is : {{ account_number }}.</p> <p>You Chose {{ period }} {{month}} as period<p>   
{% if form.errors %}
<p style="color: red;">
    Please correct the error{{ form.errors|pluralize }} below.
</p>
{% endif %} 
<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ formset.management_form }}
<table>
{% for form in formset.forms %}
{{ form }}
{% endfor %}
</table>    
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

#

@rohan

my GET method return has many variables which has to be passed into template so i tried to pass the dictionary formsetlist (after appying the changes u suggested) in following 2ways

1)

```
formset = butt( return render_to_response('budgetfinalform.html', {'account_number': c,'period':d,'month':e,'year':f,'formset': formset},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

2)

```
ctx ={'formsetlist': formset} 

 formset = butt( return render_to_response('budgetfinalform.html', {'account_number': c,'period':d,'month':e,'year':f,ctx,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

but obtained "unboundlocalerror : local variable 'formset' referenced before assignment"

Comment: You want dynamic number of formsets or form in formsets?

Comment: @Rohan i want dynamic number of formset.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
def show (request):
  #initial view processing
  # fomset_count taken as parameter or user input
  formsetlist = []
  #create formset list
  for i in range(0, formset_count):
    formsetlist.append(formset_factory(bu, extra=b))
  # other view related code

 # for GET method    
 ctx = { 'formsetlist': formset }
 return render_to_response('your_template_name', ctx,
                          context_instance = RequestContext(request)
                          )
```

In template:

```
<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
 {% for formset in formsetlist %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    <table>
    {% for form in formset.forms %}
    {{ form }}
    {% endfor %}
    </table>    
{%endfor%}
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: GET method return has many variable passd  to template,i tried to pass d dictionary formsetlist in following 2ways
1) formset = butt(
return render_to_response('budgetfinalform.html', {'account_number': c,'period':d,'month':e,'year':f,'formset': formset},context_instance=RequestContext(request))                  2) ctx ={'formsetlist': formset}
 formset = butt(
return render_to_response('budgetfinalform.html', {'account_number': c,'period':d,'month':e,'year':f,ctx,context_instance=RequestContext(request))   but obtained "unboundlocalerror : local variable 'formset' referenced b4 assgnmt"

Comment: @nimesh.iitd you are using 'formset' variable before you assigned to it. BTW, may be you should update your question with this info, reading it in comment is not much helpful.